# Stripe - save a user's card to pay them later in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I have set up a program to let users buy/sell items using stripe. The buy part works and there are no issues with it. The problem comes when I try to initiate a payout to the seller.

What I've done so far is

1). Create a card for the buyer (who will become the seller)

```
token = await stripe.tokens.create({
        card: {
            number: cardNumber,
            exp_month: exp_month,
            exp_year: exp_year,
            cvc: cvc
        },
    });
```

2). Create a source for the customer with that card

```
customerCard = await stripe.customers.createSource(
        customer.id,
        { source: token.id }
    );
```

3). When the buyer goes to sell, get their customer ID

```
cards = await stripe.customers.listSources(
                CustomerID,
                { object: 'card', limit: 1 }
            );
```

4). And finally, create a payout to the seller.

```
const payout = await stripe.payouts.create({
            amount: sellPrice,
            currency: 'usd',
            destination: cards[0].id, 
        });
```

Again, the buyer's payment works just fine but when it goes to create a payout to the seller, Stripe doesn't send the payout. The payout is listed as "incomplete" and that "The customer has not entered their payment method.". I'm not sure how else to send a payout to the seller another way and any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To send money with Stripe, you have to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect).

At a high level, it means each seller needs to have a Stripe account connected to your own account, and then you can call the [transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create) endpoint to send funds to their Stripe accounts.